# Problems with reading plist file in imessage extension with NSDictionary initWithResourceForPath methode

Tags: ios, objective-c, imessage

I have simple code like this

```
NSDictionary * languagesDict=nil;
    if(fileName)
    {
        NSString* path=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"plist"]];
        if(path)
        {
            languagesDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
            path=nil;
        }
    }
```

It works fine in main app, but in imessageexension it gives an empty dictionary.

Of course i have placed plist file I want to use in copied bundle resources, of extension target.

I have even tried to copy plist file to extension directories, by that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**1) If you want to share the .plist within App and Extension**

Your app and your extension use different default directories.

To learn the background about how extentions work, read Apples [App Extension Intro](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1).

To share files inbetween your Apps & Extensions, you need to set an `App Group Directory` and use this instead.

Step-by-step tutorial how to set it up in Obj-C can be found [here](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions).

**2) If the .plist exists within your Extensions bundle**

This code works in our extensions (Swift3):

```
let plistNameWithoutExtension = "myPlist"
let path = self.main.path(forResource: plistNameWithoutExtension, ofType: "plist")!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
let plist = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: .mutableContainers, format: nil)
```

Untested Objective-C code:

```
NSString *plistNameWithoutExtension = @"myPlist";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plistNameWithoutExtension ofType: @"plist"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but I don't understand, why should I endeble app groups. The file I want to read is in bundle resourses of extension, so if i can read image assets from this position, I also should be able to read plist file. I made another experiment with NSFileManager, and I was able to load file to NSData,but when I tried to unarchive i got nil. So it looks like I have the file but I cant read it.

Comment: And can You give me  something in objective C please

Comment: Sorry. Updated.